# Magento 2 - unable to edit category after server change

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento2

My store is running on Magento 2.1.4.

I set a dev env for my store. I duplicated the site to other account in my vps.

I set all the things correctly, change the url of the store in the db, connected the db in the `app/etc/env.php` file.

The site is working very good.

I have on problem - I can't edit any category or add a new one. I got this error in the admin control panel

> Something went wrong while saving the category.

I checked the `var/log/exception.log` file and I see this error:

> Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1142 TRIGGER command denied to user
>   '**production_user**'@'localhost' for table 'catalog_category_entity',
>   query was: UPDATE `catalog_category_entity` SET `attribute_set_id` =
>   ?, `parent_id` = ?, `path` = ?, `level` = ?, `children_count` = ?
>   WHERE (entity_id = '2') in
>   /home/devuser/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235

The issue is with **production_user**, this is not the right user (this is the production db user and not the dev db user) and this is the reason it doesn't have **TRIGGER** privilages (it doens't have privilages to this db at all) . And as I said, I edit `app/etc/env.php` file correctly and the site is working fine (I can see it connected to the dev db)

I disable the cache system, the store is on dev mode, I deploy the static files again, set the right files permissions, scan and entire db and files for the **production_user** string without any success (except the logs files with the error)

Where does it came from?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: hey, any updates?